# Properties of Rademacher functions w.r.t Lebesgue Measure

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm trying to show that the Rademacher Functions are orthogonal and independent w.r.t. Lebesgue measure. Where the Rademacher functions are the wins or losses of a player flipping a coin, $r_k: \{0,1\}^\infty \to \{\pm 1\}$. I know that a key property of the Rademacher Functions is their mutual independence. I know that another key property of the Rademacher Functions is that we may define a measure-preserving map which appends the results of a $(k+1)$ experiment to a finite sample space. This seems to be a common result assumed for Bernoulli Schemes and similar but I would like to produce a *some-what* formal proof and cannot find a suitable one.

Formally, we note that the collection of cylinder sets closed under finite union, intersection, and complement of the products of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ composes an algebra over  $X = \{0,1\}^\infty$. We may extend a measure from the $\sigma$-algebra over these sets to X and now arrive at the probability space $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mathbb{P})$, where $\mathbb{P}(X) =1$. A subset $E \subset X$ may be defined as the collected results of an ongoing series of trials, where we fix some $N$ for our purposes.
$$E_{N} = \{x = (x_1, \, \dots, x_{_N}), \text{with each}\, \,  x_j = 0 \, \, \text{or}\, \,  1, \text{for all} \, \, 1 \leq j \leq N \}$$

Certainly, we may declare a collection:
$$\bigcup E_j = E, \text{ for } 1 \leq j \leq N$$

And in addition there exists monotone classes which form the smallest $\sigma$-algebras for each fixed N. So everything seems fine at this point with the background. Set the first trial as $E_1 = \{x_1 = 0 \text{ or } 1 \} $, then $\mathbb{P}(E_1) = \frac{1}{2}$. Define the measure-preserving map which appends a new result to the collection:

$$\tau: X \to X \qquad \text{where} \qquad \tau(r_k(x)) = r_{k+1}(x)$$

Now, I believe that the explicit construction of such a transformation is identical to the Dyadic Transformation or: $x \mapsto 2x\mod(1)$.
My hope at this stage is to show that:
$$\langle r_k(x), r_{k+1}(x) \rangle = \langle r_k(x), \tau(r_{k}(x)) \rangle  = 0$$
I'm not sure if I need to pull in more theory by applying singular measures and showing for instance that the Lebesgue Decomposition Theorem provides an orthogonal and absolutely continuous part. For some Lebesgue measure $m$ over the space $(X,\mathcal{M})$. But I'm really not sure which direction to go in at this point.

I am still a bit perturbed by the various definitions of Rademacher Functions and so my apologies if the notation is confusing. I have tried to find a half-way point between measure-theory notation and more general probability notation. Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: What is _exactly_ your question? Your dismay comes hopefuly from the fact that you have somewhat browsed the abundant number of articles/papers available on this subject and found different points of view. Why don't mention one or two (significant) documents among them? This is a basic attitude to have in research, at any level.

Comment: @JeanMarie in defense of the OP, most papers and books that introduce the Rademacher functions simply define them, and assume their properties are obvious.

Comment: You could also look at page 3 of this book: https://www.amazon.com/Rademacher-System-Function-Spaces/dp/3030478890

Comment: @JeanMarie, My confusion is mostly due to the fact that I am using a text which simply states various definitions and provides somewhat elliptic directions as to how to connect them, (Stein & Shakarchi Vol 4). It's an excellent text but for someone who isn't the most assured in more abstract analysis, I find myself struggling with what is left out.

Comment: My exact question would boil down to something like what computation is necessary, using Lebesgue measure properties of Rademacher Functions, to show orthogonality?

Comment: Orthogonality follows from independence, since $E(r_k r_j) = E(r_k) E(r_j)$ for $k \ne j$.

Comment: One paper simply defined $r_k(x) = \text{sgn}( \sin (2^{k} \pi x))$, and assumed the rest was understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construction of the measure on $\{0,1\}^\infty$ is standard, and is a special case of the Kolmogorov Extension Theorem.  The $r_k$, as the projection onto the $k$th coordinate, are independent by construction.

There is a measure preserving map $M: \{0,1\}^\infty \to [0,1]$ given by
$$ M(s) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{s_j}{2^j} ,$$
in other words, the $s = (s_j)$ describe the base 2 expansion of the elements of $[0,1]$.  Note that $M$ is not injective because of the recurring 1s issue, but these are a countable set, and hence of measure zero.

Then another standard way to describe the Rademacher functions is using $\tilde r_k = r_k \circ M^{-1}$ on $[0,1]$.  Since $M$ is measure preserving, the functions $\tilde r_k$ share all the properties of the $r_k$, including independence and orthogonality.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and the reference text. That was most helpful.